# Unable to run jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, maruku

I use Github pages to host my websites,I have test it on my local machine, and it works well, but when I push my sites on Github, I got an error. It says

> The page build failed with the following error:
>
> unable to run jekyll

My `_config.yml` file

```yaml
---
auto        : false
lsi         : false
pygments    : true
permalink   : none
markdown    : maruku

maruku:
    use_divs:   true 
    use_tex:  true 
    png_engine : blahtex
    png_dir    : images/latex/
    png_url    : /images/latex/
```

I have searched the web, but can't find any useful ideas. Who can help me?

I have resorted to Github, they sent me the log, here is the error:
Maruku: Using extended syntax for div elements.\nMaruku: Using LaTeX extension. Images in `images/latex/`.\n/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/ext/math/mathml_engines/blahtex.rb:40:in `convert_to_png_blahtex': Blahtex error: empty output (RuntimeError)\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/ext/math/to_html.rb:64:in` send'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/ext/math/to_html.rb:64:in `render_png'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/ext/math/to_html.rb:120:in` to_html_equation'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/output/to_html.rb:970:in `send'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/output/to_html.rb:970:in` array_to_html'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/output/to_html.rb:961:in `each'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/output/to_html.rb:961:in` array_to_html'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/output/to_html.rb:956:in `children_to_html'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/output/to_html.rb:50:in` to_html'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/converters/markdown.rb:120:in `convert'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:46:in` transform'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:84:in `do_layout'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/post.rb:189:in` render'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:193:in `render'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:192:in` each'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:192:in `render'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:40:in` process'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/jekyll:250\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/jekyll:19:in `load'\n\tfrom /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/jekyll:19\n"

From the log, We can see  the problem is `convert_to_png_blahtex': Blahtex error: empty output (RuntimeError). I read the blahtex code,

```
if png.name != 'png'
   maruku_error "Blahtex error: \n#{doc}"
   return nil
end
```

But, png files are there. Anyone has encountered this problem?

Comment: Where are you seeing the error message?

Comment: Github sends me a system message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the _config.yml file is the problem. I've pushed an invalid one to my site and the pages still render fine. That said, try removing your _config.yml all together. Github pages work fine without it for me. If the page still fails to render, you know it's something else.

Comment: Thank you! I delete it, and it works except for the math equation as the config file specify the blahtex image file's location. But I check my _config.yml file, it seems to be no error.

Answer (score 0):

## Don't use maruku

maruku hasnt had an update since June 2010.

Personally I prefer kramdown.